# Selecting find updated column and row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+
|   Col1  |   Col2  |   timestamp   |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 6050000 | 6030000 | 1325241121990 |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 6050000 | 6040000 | 1325241611269 |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 6050000 | 6050000 | 1325248254109 |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 6060000 | 6050000 | 1325248455780 |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 6060000 | 6050000 | 1325354237099 |
+---------+---------+---------------+
```

I need to find out in each row which of `Col1` Or `Col2` has been updated most recently in relation to previous rows.

For example in the above table:

- rows #2, #3 `Col2` was the most recent update
- rows #4, #5 `Col1` was the most recent update.

Question: How can I find the row that last updated of a column up to when the next record occurs in SQL ?

My target DBMS are Mysql, SQlite & MS Access.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t quite understand your database setup. What are the numbers in Col1 / Col2 for?

Comment: Sounds like you need `timestamp1` and `timestamp2`.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel: They are two parameters of a same factor that is gotten from different sources and I need the lately changed one of them.

Comment: @Ben: No , Both numbers are gotten at the same time but from different sources

Comment: Can Col1 or Col2 include Nulls?

Comment: @HansUp: No, 3 queries are good too, No they can't be `Null`

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a funky query, but this is what it looks like:

```
select
    case when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 'Col1 is the same' else 'Col1 is updated' end as Col1Status,
    case when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 'Col2 is the same' else 'Col2 is updated' end as Col2Status
from
    table t1
    inner join table t2 on
         t2.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table t3 where t1.timestamp > t3.timestamp)
```

It looks a little prettier if you happen to have a unique identifier on your table.